# Differentiating tables and views in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Tags: sql-server

I have a view which selects information from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, which seems to give me both columns and views. Is there an easy way to tell which rows are columns and which are views? Should I do a comparison with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS? I need both columns and views, I just want to be able to tell which is which.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to do a left outer join to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS to see if they are views or not.

```
select CASE WHEN b.TABLE_NAME is not null then 'view' else 'table' end OBJECT_TYPE,
    a.*
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS b ON a.TABLE_CATALOG = b.TABLE_CATALOG
    AND a.TABLE_SCHEMA = b.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Can you expand on that? I have the join, but I want a column to indicate whether it's a view or not and I'm having trouble getting the syntax right.

Comment: I've added some sample code.

Comment: Any reason for not using an `INNER JOIN` instead?

Comment: The Op asked for which ones were views and which weren't. An inner join would have removed the ones for tables.

Answer (score 10):

The query posted by [@mrdenny](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34/mrdenny) didn't seem to return reliable data for me. I had more luck this way.

```
select b.TABLE_TYPE, a.*
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES b ON a.TABLE_CATALOG = b.TABLE_CATALOG
    AND a.TABLE_SCHEMA = b.TABLE_SCHEMA
    AND a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: +if you want only tables you add "AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'" to the left outer join.